# Change menu selected item color

Tags: windows, colors, selection

In windows 10 is there a registry trick to change the color of a selected item of a menu, for example in a right click menu or a toolbar menu or a sidebar menu such as explorer folder tree view.

I'm aware that windows has changed a lot since windows 8 but maybe its still possible ..

My problem is that when I use 'find' in regedit it is very hard to see which key is selected if there is a matching result to my search.

Answer (score -1):

HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Colors/ contains some values (can't remember which ones) that make so highlighted text (including clicked on keys) is red instead of blue.

Comment: Please clarify your answer it seems sort of incomplete.

Comment: Ill have a look.